# Make 1998 using the least possible digits 8

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Make the number 1998 using the minimum amount of digits 8.

Your allowed operations are +, -, *, /, ^, % (percent).

You need not use only integers 8: 88 and the likes are acceptable.

You must only use 8 as a digit, nothing else.

This puzzle comes from an old friend's school DMs. He said the best that could be done was 10, so I'm turning to the community to see if you can do it better.

Have fun.

Comment: Can we write two eights together to make 88?

Comment: @Andrew Viola! We have got it with 9 8's (by @HerbWolfe)

Comment: @Quark-epoch I got a nine-$8$ solution around 15 minutes before Herb Wolfe :-)

Comment: The real question is, what about 8 8s?

Comment: Adding concatenation really does change the question.

Comment: @BenBarden agreed, but as of yet, there's no evidence of it also changing the answer :-)

Comment: @Bass If we allow _proper_ concatenation, it will definitely change the answer :) E.g. 888/8 * concat(8/8, 8) = 111 * concat(1, 8) = 111 * 18 = 1998.

Comment: What is 8: 88? Colon is not defined as a valid operator, did you mean 8.88 (as in 888 / 100)? Also, it doesn't look like you're limiting the numbers we can use. Does that mean 1999 - 1 is a valid answer? I know the question implies only 8s, but I see no attempt to prevent this particular loophole.

Comment: @Nolonar `8:88` is not a number; it means that we may use integers other than 8, such as 88 and so on.

Comment: @Nolonar I guess he was saying that you don't have to only use integer equal to 8. The colon is here to point to the example after it.

Comment: According to [this consensus on meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles), these types of questions *must* have a provably optimized answer. It may be the case that the only valid answers are brute-force computer searches. **To answerers: Answers *must* have a proof of optimality.** An answer without a proof of optimality is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Deusovi - Did... you just delete all the answers? O_O

Comment: @Deusovi - Also, if so, then my answer should probably go too, because I do **not** have a proof of optimality either. I searched a pretty large set of expressions, but there's an infinity of possibilities and the data types used don't fare so well with extreme numbers. There was already one answer (with 1875 `%` signs) that would be impossible for my code to find.

Comment: I've temporarily locked this question due to concerns about answer validity and how the question falls under [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles/) - see [this discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51689908#51689908) in The Sphinx's Lair for more details.

Answer (score 32):

Found a solution with **8 eights**, using concatenation and finally finding some use for the percent sign:

> $$\frac{88 + 8\times8 +8 -8\% -8\%}{8\%}$$
>  $$ = \frac{88 + 64 + 8 -.08 -.08}{.08} = \frac{160}{.08} - \frac{.08}{.08}- \frac{.08}{.08} = 160*12.5 -2 = 1998$$

**EDITED** *(much later..)*: Found another, without concatenation this time:

> $$8 \times (8+8) \times (8+8) - \frac{8}{8\%+8\%} $$
>  $$ = 8\times16\times16 - \frac{8}{.16} = 2048 - 50 = 1998 $$

Comment: After checking the other answers, I'd like to add a particularly smug wave (Hi there!) to Rand's first answer in particular :-)

Comment: Darn you beat me to your second solution! :P (my **9** solution is a derpy way to do yours)

Comment: @Adam, I totally stole the way to make the 50 from your post, the unusual use of the parens and the percent sign caught my eye, and I realised you had invented a totally brilliant way of creating the 50 I remembered desperately needing an hour ago. (The upvote on [your answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/88992/36023) is mine, more would definitely be in order.)

Comment: Ah, damn, I was so close. Well done.

Comment: +1 for managing to pull it off without concatenation.  Well done!

Comment: At the time this comment was sent, there were 8 upvotes on the question, 8 upvotes on the answer, 8 8's used to create this answer, and 8 answers.

Comment: You did it. You're a *legend.*

Comment: @Andrew Oh, you flatter me. I'm not [a legend](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/43/legendary), I'm only [epic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/42/epic). :-)

Comment: Based on the rules established by [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) and the consensus around it, an answer must have justification for why the solution is optimal. Without that, this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Deusovi sorry, but how exactly do you think such a proof can be accomplished??? I literally do not think such a proof (in the mathematical sense) is possible given the infinitude of possibilities.

Answer (score 20):

OK, so I took a different approach. Seeing as I couldn't come up with anything interesting, I decided - f-it, let's make the computer try! And wrote a little program that tries all the possibilities. The code can be found [here on PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/ZEa9y3Pw).

There are two things of note about the `%` operator:

- I treated it as an unary operator which divides by 100. So it can be stacked too: `(8+8)%% = 0.0016`
- Since you can potentially add as many `%` operators as you want to a single operand, I had to put in some kind of limit. Initially I set it to max 3 `%` operators in a row, but later changed to 1 to make it faster.

With that in mind the results are...

I couldn't find any expressions with 6 `8`s or less. But with 7 `8`s they started coming in. Here's one:

> $$ 8+\frac{8+8-8\%}{(88-8)\%\%}=8+\frac{15.92}{0.008}=8+1990=1998$$

The total results for 7x`8` with no more than 1 `%` in a row are below. They are all in [Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) because that was easier for me to produce. Converting them to "normal" notation is straightforward, but tedious, so I'll leave that to someone else. :)

> `+ 8/+ 8- 8% 8%-% 88% 8` 
>  `+ 8/-+ 8 8% 8%-% 88% 8` 
>  `- 8/-% 8+ 8 8%-% 88% 8` 
>  `+ 8/- 8-% 8 8%-% 88% 8` 
>  `+ 8/+- 8% 8 8%-% 88% 8` 
>  `- 8/--% 8 8 8%-% 88% 8` 
>  `+/+ 8- 8% 8%-% 88% 8 8` 
>  `+/-+ 8 8% 8%-% 88% 8 8` 
>  `+/- 8-% 8 8%-% 88% 8 8` 
>  `+/+- 8% 8 8%-% 88% 8 8` 
>  `+/-% 8+ 8 8%-% 8% 88 8` 
>  `+/--% 8 8 8%-% 8% 88 8` 
>  `- 8/+ 8- 8% 8%-% 8% 88` 
>  `- 8/-+ 8 8% 8%-% 8% 88` 
>  `+ 8/-% 8+ 8 8%-% 8% 88` 
>  `- 8/- 8-% 8 8%-% 8% 88` 
>  `- 8/+- 8% 8 8%-% 8% 88` 
>  `+ 8/--% 8 8 8%-% 8% 88`

**Note:** I've checked all formulas with 6x`8` and up to 2 `%` signs in row and didn't find anything. I also checked all 5x`8` with up to 3 `%` signs in row. No results. However **this doesn't prove that it's impossible to do with 6 or less `8`.** This only means that my code cannot find such combinations because it's beyond what it is capable of. The `double` data type does have its limits, and [Legorin showed](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/89037/42682) that you can have a legit answer with 1875 `%` signs in row (which is awesome, by the way). The code could be further improved to both increase accuracy and speed, but I've already wasted enough time on it as it is. If you want to give it a go, be my guest! :)

Comment: Impressive code. Did you try every possibility, so you could rule out the possibility of using less than 8 8s?

Comment: Wait, you didn't include any exponent, did you?

Comment: @EricDuminil - I added exponent and moved from `float` to `double`. That's a pretty serious performance hit, so I'm still waiting for results. There was nothing with 6x`8`, but 7x`8` is taking a good while.

Comment: @EricDuminil - Aaaand done! We have solutions with 7x`8`! However they all seem to depend on "percentalizing" subresults. I guess that's acceptable?

Comment: Huh... I tried runnign 6x8 with double-percents and got some results too! The expressions look spaghettified. I'll have to verify those. At these magnitudes, it's likely that floating point errors are creeping in.

Comment: 5x8 with 3 percents didn't get results. And it took a good while. Seems like adding another % in row increases the processing time exponentially. I won't try 4 % in row, I don't think there will be any results.

Comment: What about exponentiation?

Comment: @EricDuminil - I added that. And the 6x`8` solutions include that too. But for 7x`8` it seems that the transition to `double` was more important.

Comment: @EricDuminil - Ahh it was a bug. Fixed it, trying again.

Comment: @EricDuminil - OK, final results. 6x`8` with 2x`%` didn't yield any results.

Answer (score 15):

I have a solution with 12 8s

> $((8+8) \times (8+8) \times 8) - (8\times8) + (8+8) - \frac{8+8}{8}$

Updated, another with 9 8s

> $\frac{8888-8}{8} + 888$

Comment: I added some maths formatting - hope you don't mind :-)

Comment: Ooh, nice: your nine-8 solution is a polished version of my ten-8 one.

Comment: Based on the rules established by [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) and the consensus around it, an answer must have justification for why the solution is optimal. Without that, this is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 15):

I found another solution with 8.

> $$(\frac{8}{8\%\%...\%\%}^{8\%\%} - \frac{8}{8})\frac{8+8}{8}=1998$$

the %%...%% is 1875 % symbols

> $$\%=\frac{1}{100}$$
>  $$8\%\%=\frac{1}{1250}$$
>  $$\frac{8}{8\%\%...\%\%}=1000^{1250}$$

therefore

> $$\frac{8}{8\%\%...\%\%}^{8\%\%} = 1000$$
>  $$1000 - \frac{8}{8} = 999$$
>  $$999(\frac{8+8}{8})=1998$$

Comment: By far the most amazing answer (+1)

Comment: you can also do 8/((88-8)%%) to get 1000 but thats less fun and 4 8s

Comment: Based on the rules established by [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) and the consensus around it, an answer must have justification for why the solution is optimal. Without that, this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Can we get the number of percent symbols up to 1998, while still producing the number 1998?

Comment: Actually, yes, you can. Both `8/8` and `(8+8)/8` allow you to add as many `%` symbols as you like, as long as you do it symmetrically to both sides of the fraction. So `8/8=8%/8%=8%%/8%%=...` and `(8+8)/8=(8%+8%)/8%=...`. Using this you can get up to 1998 `%` in total.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a hilarious solution for **9**

> $(\frac{8+8}{8})^{\frac{88}{8}}-\frac{8}{(8+8)\%}=1998$

For research purposes I'll also include my kinda illegal solution for **7**

> $\frac{8+8}{8}(\frac{8}{.8\%}-\frac{8}{8})=1998$

Comment: You won... if we include the dot. I didn't allow the dot to be used but nice work still.

Comment: Based on the rules established by [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) and the consensus around it, an answer must have justification for why the solution is optimal. Without that, this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Your second solution can be reduced to 6: $\dfrac{8+8}{.8\%}-\dfrac{8+8}{8}=1998$

Comment: @Nilster Why stop there? $\frac {8+8-.8\%-.8\%}{.8\%}$

Answer (score 9):

A solution with **nine** $8$s:

> $$\frac{88+(8\times8)+8}{8\%} - \frac{8+8}{8}$$

i.e.

> $1100      +       800            +      100      -      2$, taking advantage of the fact that $\%$ is an allowed operation.

A very simple solution with **ten** $8$s (which I'm surprised nobody else has done):

> $$\frac{8888}{8} + 888 - \frac{8}{8}$$

Comment: I saw this puzzle on a site and thought to ask this SE about it. The given solution on the site had ten 8s, so this is technically an improvement. Nice work, Rand!

Comment: Wow! I was expecting this to be still not optimal, since in a previous comment you mentioned eight 8s.

Comment: Well... I misremembered.

It was not a real site. It was a DM with a friend in school. I'll make sure to mention this in an edit.

Comment: I didn't see your solution with 10, but I added a similar one with 9 8s.

Comment: the reason no one had done the "very simple solution" was that things like 88, 888, etc were not declared as permissible until relatively shortly before your answer.

Comment: Based on the rules established by [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) and the consensus around it, an answer must have justification for why the solution is optimal. Without that, this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Because you can factor ${1 \over 8}$ to get ${8888 - 8 \over 8} + 888$.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution with $9$ eights, without using the % operator:

> $$ \frac{888}{8} ( 8+8 + \frac{8+8}{8}) = 111*18=1998$$

Comment: Based on the rules established by [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) and the consensus around it, an answer must have justification for why the solution is optimal. Without that, this is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to a comment from Ben Barden, here is another way of achieving **11** 8s

> $8+8+\left(\left(\frac{8+8}{8}\right)^8 - 8\right)\times 8-\frac{8+8}{8}$

Comment: If someone got 8 8s that'd be cool.

Comment: you could pull the same trick I did, and shave it down to 11 as well.

Comment: @BenBarden Thanks, totally missed that factorisation, +1 for you.

Comment: ...and +1 back for being the originator of my solution's ancestor.

Comment: Based on the rules established by [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) and the consensus around it, an answer must have justification for why the solution is optimal. Without that, this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Deusovi at the time this answer was posted, 11 was as good as we'd managed to get.

Answer (score 4):

My first try, with ten:

> $\frac{8888}{8} + 888 - \frac{8}{8}$

Only 4 operators

Comment: This one is already in [my answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/88985/5373). Nice one though!

Comment: Thanks! Similarly, I’ve just got another solution which I found was already posted by another user. Such is the game!

Comment: @Brandon_J what makes you say that? I see no connection to Rubio whatsoever!

Comment: Based on the rules established by [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) and the consensus around it, an answer must have justification for why the solution is optimal. Without that, this is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Stealing gloriously from the work of others, I have it down to 11:

> $(((8+8) \times (8+8) - 8) \times 8) + (8+8) - \frac{8+8}{8}$

Comment: I added some maths formatting - hope you don't mind :-)

Comment: Based on the rules established by [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) and the consensus around it, an answer must have justification for why the solution is optimal. Without that, this is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you allow concatenation of intermediate results (not just the original $8$s), here's a solution with $7$ eights:

> $$\frac{888}{8}*\left(\frac88 8 \right)$$
>  The concatenation $\left(\frac88 8 \right)$ works out to $18$.

Comment: If concatenation is not specified, would the assumed result of the equation in your parenthesis not be 8 (i.e. 8/8*8 = 8)? I think concatenation is usually denoted with || i.e. 8/8||8 - Although I stand to be corrected!

Comment: You literally stole this answer from trolley813's comment

Comment: @Adam I didn't see the comment. So you may consider it "stealing", but I came up with it independently. Nevertheless, thanks for pointing it out. I will delete my answer.

Comment: If you allow that you can do much better: $\frac{8+8-8\%}{8\%}||8$

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward solution with 9 8s:

> $(\frac{88 - 8}{8} + 8) \times (\frac{888}{8})$

Comment: Based on the rules established by [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) and the consensus around it, an answer must have justification for why the solution is optimal. Without that, this is a comment, not an answer.