# Make 38 using the least possible digits 8

Tags: mathematics, optimization, formation-of-numbers

This is a follow up question to [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/88978/make-1998-using-the-least-possible-digits-8), which was:

> Make the number 1998 using the minimum amount of digits 8.
>
> Your allowed operations are +, -, *, /, ^, % (percent).
>
> You need not use only integers 8: 88 and the likes are acceptable.
>
> You must only use 8 as a digit, nothing else.
>
> This puzzle comes from an old friend's school DMs. He said the best
> that could be done was 10, so I'm turning to the community to see if
> you can do it better.

But this time you need to find **38** instead of 1998, still with the least amount of digit 8.

Have fun!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Five $8$s

> $88- \frac 8 {8\%+8\%}$

Comment: What does the % operator mean? Edit: Ah, it's just "8%", not an operator.

Comment: @Clockwork technically, it is a (unary) operator. But you are right, it's just percent.

Answer (score 6):

Here is seven 8s

> $$\left(\frac{88}{8} + 8\right) \times \left(\frac{8+8}{8} \right) $$

Answer (score 6):

Here's six 8s:

> $$\left(\dfrac{88}{.8}-8\times8\right)-8$$

Answer (score 4):

Eight 8's:

> $\dfrac{88}8+8+\dfrac{88}8+8=38$

Answer (score 2):

Using 5 8s :

> $\dfrac{8 + 8 + 8}{.8} + 8$